# Which Linux tool to do a full backup of pc on my LAN running windows?

Tags: linux, backup, desktop

I would like to backup my small home LAN computers (5 of them) using my ubuntu server (but I can change distro if needed).
I've read about backuppc but I don't understand if I can fully backup a pc while it is working and obtain the same working pc if, e.g., my hd dies a few days later.
When I try the backup of the whole pc entering admin user and pass in backuppc I get errors (probably because files are in use).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What service in Ubuntu work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Bacula. Its Windows agent can use Volume Shadow Copy Service. You can read more [here](http://www.bacula.org/2.4.x-manuals/en/main/Windows_Version_Bacula.html#SECTION004260000000000000000)